# Expected value of continuous probability distribution

Tags: python, expected-value, continuous-data, kernel-smoothing

I'm using `statsmodels.nonparametric.KDEMultivariate` to generate continuous probability distributions with kernel density estimation. The distribution is created using `statsmodels.nonparametric.KDEMultivariate(data=[time, measurement])` to create a distribution, and then if I want to find a discretised most likely measurement from my distribution for a particular time, I can iterate through with:

```
for x in range(10):
    probability_of_x = distribution.pdf([TIME, x])
```

Where `TIME` is the fixed time value for which I want to obtain a "best prediction".

What I'm struggling with is how to work out the expected value from a distribution like this, as I know that iterating through as I am to find the "best prediction" is the wrong way to go about it.

Is there a python library or something similar that I could use to get the expected value for a fixed time?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not quite familiar with `statsmodels`, but if you have data values, $x_1, \ldots, x_n$, and probabilities of these values $p_1, \ldots, p_n$ given to you by the function `distribution.pdf()`, then an estimator for the expected value could be
$$
\widehat{E[X]} = \sum_{i=1}^n p_i x_i,
$$
which might be something like this

```
ave = 0
time = 0
for datum in data:
    ave += datum * distribution.pdf([time, x])
    time += 1
print ave
```

Maybe not though. Like @michaelchernick says, this forum isn't really for programming help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I was originally going to use a method like this, but surely discretising a continuous distribution and then working out the expected value from this will result in a value that's too small?
With regards to the comments about programming help, it seems like my question is better suited to StackOverflow. :)

Comment: @helencrump all data is discrete, so I wouldn't worry about that. I don't see why it would be too small, though. I don't have much experience with nonparametric density estimation, so I am embarassed to say that I do not know how people use the density curve to do anything. With parametric estimation, you get parameter estimates $\hat{\theta}$, and then just plug them into the function of interest usually.

Comment: Marking this as the answer as I realised that I hadn't normalised any of my probabilities, which is why my results were always so small when using this method. Thanks so much for the help!